# "Incompatible data types in combination" leading to "Could not initialize a collection" in JPA with an inherited bidirectional relation

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I am trying to implement the following diagram in Hibernate, JPA.

[image]

I tried to implement it this way.

For the farm

```
@Entity
public class Farm implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "farm", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, targetEntity=AbstractAnimals.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AbstractAnimal> animals = new ArrayList<AbstractAnimals>();

}
```

For the Abstract Annimal

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractAnimal implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "farmId", nullable = false)
    private Farm farm;

    ... other attributes and getter and setter
}
```

For the Abstract Mammalian

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class AbstractMammalian extends AbstractAnimal implements Serializable{
    ... other attributes and getter and setter
}
```

For all the annimals

```
@Entity
public abstract class 'Animal' extends 'supertype' implements Serializable{

    ... other attributes and getter and setter
}
```

When I tried to get all the farm animals I get the following error

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [my.example.Farm.animals#24]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2173)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:627)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
    at my.example.persistence.Farm.getAnnimals(Farm.java:132)
    at my.example.DTOFactory.updateFarmDTO(DTOFactory.java:269)
    at my.example.DTOFactory.createFarmDTO(DTOFactory.java:250)
    at my.example.DTOFactory.createChickenDTO(DTOFactory.java:183)
    at my.example.ChickenServiceImpl.createChicken(ChickenServiceImpl.java:62)
    at my.example.ChickenServiceTest.createChickenWithHome(ChickenServiceTest.java:243)
    at my.example.ChickenServiceTest.testRejectChickenHome(ChickenServiceTest.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data types in combination
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2166)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data types in combination
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.BitType.getAggregateType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.Type.getAggregateType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveTypesPartOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolveTypesPartOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableSubqueryOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
```

**Edit**

```
EntityManager manager = null;
EntityTransaction tx = null;
TaskDTO result = null;

try {
    manager = PersistenceUtils.getEntityManager();
    try
    {
       tx = manager.getTransaction();
       tx.begin();
       Farm farm = manager.find(Farm.class, 
       Farmer farmer = manager.find(farmer.class, farmerDtoID);
       int status = AnimalService.IDLE;

       if (birth.before(new Date())){
           status = TaskService.UNBORN;
       }
       Chicken newChicken = new Chicken(name, farm, user, birth, death, status);
       manager.persist(newChicken);
       tx.commit();
       result = DTOFactory.createChickenDTO(newChicken, true);
   }
   finally
   {
       if (tx.isActive())
       {
           tx.rollback();
       }
   }
}
finally
{
    if (manager != null)
    {
        manager.close();
    }
 }
 return result;
```

Comment: You'll need to show the JPQL you're using for this query. Also what is the `my.example.persistence.Request` class referred to in the exception?

Comment: sorry code anomynisation mistake. And what is JPQL ?

Comment: The query you used in your call to entityManager.createQuery() Or did you just call entityManager.find()?

Comment: Can you show the code segment where you opened the session and queried the collection?

Comment: No query, the query is a getter

Comment: It's very hard to say what the problem is, because the code you've shown us is not real code. It doesn't even compile, and were one to fix the compilation errors, it wouldn't describe valid JPA entities.

Comment: @Tom Anderson : +1 On comment. Your are totaly right, but for I can't show the real code. But the architecture of the code I gave is exactly the same, just names have changed so it can be any application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're doing wrong. You just haven't shown us enough code to detect the problem.

Here is how you can do it right:

- https://bitbucket.org/twic/farm/src

That is an implementation of the same object model, but in a way which works fine. There is a Gradle script which will generate and apply the relevant SQL; you can then run the Main class to insert and query some data, including calling `Farm.getAnimals()`.

There are a few differences between my code and yours. Mine is simpler; i have left out the various unnecessary things like specifying column names, explicitly stating that collections are lazy, making entity classes serializable, etc. I have also opted to annotate `AbstractMammal` as an `@Entity`, not a `@MappedSuperclass`. I saw no reason not to. I tried it both ways, and both ways worked.

So, whatever it is that's going wrong for you, it is a difference between your code and mine. It could be a bug in your JPA implementation. It is more likely to be a bug in your annotations. I suggest you clone my code, make it run, then start modifying it bit by bit to be more like your code, and see when it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** It's just a guess.

Try to do without forced collection initialization. Something like that:

```
@Entity
public class Farm implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "farm", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, targetEntity=AbstractAnimals.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AbstractAnimal> animals;

}
```

Comment: Try to annotate getter instead of the field.

Comment: Having during maven compilation : Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Farm, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(animals)]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same here with a few differences.
Check these things too:
1. Set Fetch Type of farm to EAGER in your `AbstractAnimal` class.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "farmId", nullable = false)
private Farm farm;
```

2. Put this annotation above your getter. `@XmlTransient`

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Tom Anderson I have managed to solve my problem. The solution was to use Hibernate 4.1 instead of 3.6 and change the methods in the persistance helper from `'Session'.connection()` 
to

```
'Session'.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection c) throws SQLException {

    }
}
```